# Is there a java library or code example available that optimize parameters via LBFGS by giving current parameters, gradient and cost/loss(function)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mathematical-optimization, deep-learning

What I m looking for is a function like this:

**optimizeByLBFGS(CurrentParamters,GradientOfParamters,Loss/Cost) return: optimized paramters**

Then I will use the returned optimized paramters and calculate the new loss/cost and feed them again ... and again... in this function. What can I use for this purpose?

Something like [scipy.optimize.minimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) in python for java?

Current paramters and gradients are availabe in a array / vector in the form of 100 rows and 1 column. Is something avaialbe

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at LBFGSOptimizer in the RISO project at Github. See: https://github.com/robert-dodier/riso

Comment: thanks, you mean https://github.com/robert-dodier/riso/blob/master/src/riso/numerical/LBFGSOptimizer.java , if I find nothing more useful for my case, I will use yours :-(

Answer (score 2):

There is one in Spark:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/LBFGS.html

And I heard that this one is nice too:

https://github.com/brendano/myutil/blob/master/src/util/LBFGS.java